# Работа с файлами Python. Переменная и split

Tags: python, файлы, split, работа-с-текстом

Нужно создать вручную файл( но я пока сделал чтобы он создавался сам) в файле содержатся предложение потом в коде надо считать содержимое этого файла в переменную. Не понимаю переменная это как? Потом нужно разбить эту текстовую переменную в массив( я так понимаю это с помощью split, только куда её вставлять) потом в этот масив нужно добавить 4 строки любых и записать всё в новый файл. Тоесть из первого файла надо выдернуть этот масив и добавить новые 4 строки(которые вводишь через консоль) и чтобы создавался новый файл с этим текстом? Вот код, правда я не догоняю как перенести с одного файла в другой новый текст.Получилось только добавлять в него строки и сохранят его же отредоктированным.

```
f = open("tekst.txt", 'w+')

line1 = input()
line2 = input()
line3 = input()
line4 = input()

f.write(line1)
f.write(" ")
f.write(line2)
f.write(" ")
f.write(line3)
f.write(" ")
f.write(line4)
f.close()

f = open("tekst.txt", 'r')
print("Содержание файла:\n", f.read())
f.close()

f = open("tekst.txt", 'w+')

f.write(line2)
f.write(" ")
f.write(line4)
f.close()

f = open("tekst.txt", 'r')
print("Слова в чётных позициях:\n", f.read())
f.close
```

Comment: попробуйте `lines = f.readlines()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы на правильно пути! Но вам нужно запомнить строки прочитанные из tekst.txt для этого их нужно записать в переменную. В моем примере это список `words`. Затем модифицируем список и пишем в новый файл.

Для работы с файлами хорошим тоном является использование контекстного оператора with, который контролирует открытие и закрытия файла

```python
with open("file.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    words = f.read().split()

for i in range(4):
    words.extend(str(input("Введите строку: ")).split())

with open("file_out.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for i in range(len(words)):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            print(i)
            f.write(words[i] + " ")
```

input:

```
Введите строку: Привет
Введите строку: Солнышко
Введите строку: Зебра
Введите строку: bar
```

file.txt

```
Hello, world! Hello, python!
```

file_out.txt

```
Hello, Hello, Привет Зебра
```

Comment: Спасибо! Но у меня получается Строка 1 появляется сразу после Hello, python! Как это исправить? И сделать пробел между ними, хочу чтобы было всё в одну строку а не в столбик(убрал \n)

Comment: Добавьте " " после "!":
`lines[1] = lines[1] + " "`
И " " перед словом "Строка..." >>> " Строка..."

Comment: Получилось. Вот теперь я не могу понять, у нас в конце команды открывается файл с названием file_out.txt. В нём содержится текст( у меня это например Klara Ykrala Koralli)+ 4 строки которые мы добавили( я сделал добавление своих строк тобишь ввод через консоль `lines.append(" " + input() + " ")`, но мне нужно оставить только те слова(строки) которые находятся на чётных позициях это: Ykrala, 1строка(которую вводим) и 3 строка. От остальных избавится как это сделать?

Comment: Отредактировал свой ответ, под ваше условие. (если я правильно его понял)

Comment: Спасибо всё получилось!